# Linked Worksheet changes to read only after data is imported in report

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I'm facing issue with Linked Table, Access DB and Excel Report. I would provide the scenario, please suggest for a solution if you are aware:
 1. Admin user, creates Linked Table in Access DB. This table is open 24/7. Data inserted to DB via Linked Table/Worksheet
 2. End User, generates the report from Access DB
 3. If the admin user does any data update and when the end user refreshes the report, the Linked worksheet changes to "Read-Only"

**Note:**
Linked worksheet and Access DB stored in Server-1
End users connected to Server-1 (or) different

This same scenario worked fine in 2007, but its causing issue after migration to 2013.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can install the Power Query Add-ins and select the option **“From Database”** 
**=> “from Microsoft access database”** to import the data from access to excel (to generate the report for End users)

Download Power query from below link:

https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/

Refer for more details:

https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/

**Note:**

This features is already available in Excel 2016

Answer (score -1):

Your post is not clear.  Let's review:

1. Admin user, creates Linked Table in Access DB. This table is open 24/7. Data inserted to DB via Linked Table/Worksheet

*** do you mean that the Access db is linking to an excel file?  ... if so what is meant by "inserted to db" ??  There are 2 choices: linked to excel - or - import excel data into Access table

2. End User, generates the report from Access DB

*** ok

3. If the admin user does any data update and when the end user refreshes the report, the Linked worksheet changes to "Read-Only"

*** admin is changing data in excel sheet?

*** In general; Access does not like an excel opened when it is communicating to it. i.e. generating a report. It wants exclusive use.  There should be no problem working in the Excel when the Access app is closed.